# Handling custom Exception with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to make a the code that will catch a `PhoneNumberInUseException` that is thrown by the `ServiceImpl` however, the code below always go for the `else` statement.

```
@Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert("Failed create account.");
                if (caught instanceof PhoneNumberInUseException) {
                    Window.alert("Sorry, but the phone number is already used.");
                } else {
                    Window.alert(caught.toString());
                }

            }
```

The `PhoneNumberInUseException extends RuntimeException`

Right now I am just showing this through Window.alert, however I will be doing client-side logic for handling the exception, that is why I can't simply use `IllegalArgumentException` which works just fine passing exception string from server to client.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to extend `PhoneNumnberInUseException` from `IllegalArgumentException` instead of just `Exception` and make it `Serializable`, I don't know if this is the correct approach though:

```
public class PhoneNumnberInUseException extends IllegalArgumentException implements Serializable{
    public PhoneNumnberInUseException(){
        super();
    }
    public PhoneNumnberInUseException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Realistically, you could have kept your code exactly as it was and just declared that your RPC method throws that exception: `public void doSomething(Object someObject) throws PhoneNumberInUseException;`. GWT would only propagate a `RuntimeException` to the client if it had been explicitly declared via `throws`.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell I see, the reason I used RuntimeException is because I need to throw exception inside a if-else statement, whereas if I extend from Exception I'm getting syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

If your `PhoneNumberInUseException` class looks something like this:

```
public class PhoneNumberInUseException extends RuntimeException {

    public PhoneNumberInUseException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and you're throwing it in the service like this:

```
throw new PhoneNumberInUseException();
```

then your code should be firing correctly. That is, of course, assuming your service has declared that it throws `PhoneNumberInUseException`, like this:

```
public interface SomeService extends RemoteService {
    void doSomething(Object someObject) throws PhoneNumberInUseException;
}

public interface SomeServiceAsync {
    void doSomething(Object someObject, AsyncCallback callback);
}

public class SomeServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements SomService {
    public void doSomething(Object someObject) throws PhoneNumberInUseException {
        if(somethingHappened) {
            throw new PhoneNumberInUseException();
        } else {
            doSomethingCool();
        }
    }
}
```

If after you've made sure everything *should* be working correctly, you might want to put a breakpoint on the line

```
if (caught instanceof PhoneNumberInUseException)
```

and figure out what the class of `caught` is. If it's **not** `PhoneNumberInUseException`, you probably haven't [read the documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#exceptions) very well.